# Selecting JSON item from XML which was converted to JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have an external XML feed which needs parsing. Because I'm working with node.js the feed gets converted to JSON. Javascript is then used to extract te relevant information.

The XML looks like this:

```
<name>blahblahblah</name> 
<price currency="EUR">10.95</price>
```

Converted to JSON:

```
name: [ 'blahblahblah' ],
price: 
   [ { _: '10.95',
   '$': { currency: 'EUR' } } ]
```

Now selecting name is easy:

```
var name = record.name[0] ;
print name; //outputs blahblahblah
```

I've tried:

```
var price = record.price[0];
var price = record.price;
var price = record.price._;
var price = record.price._[0];
```

But these obviously didn't work ;-) I would like to be able to select the price, and more specificly, select te price based on it's attribute ("currency"). I.e. in XML: //price["@currency='EUR'"]

Comment: What about `record.price[0]._` or `record.price[0]["_"];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var record={name: [ 'blahblahblah' ], price:     [ { _: '10.95',    '$': { currency: 'EUR' } } ]};
record.price[0]._ // giving price 
record.price[0].$.currency // giving currency
```

Comment: Awesome, tnx! :-) But is there a also way to get the "price" by looking for an element where "currency=EUR"?